# ORMLite ID field cannot be compared

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I have several classes, all of which have an ID field declared as `Integer` the next way:

```
@Expose
@DatabaseField(columnName = "_id", id = true)
private Integer idField;
```

Everything compiles and runs correctly, but when I simply try to check if a record exists:

```
Integer idField = 1;
result = DBHelper.getHelper().getClassDAO().idExists(idField);
```

I get the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field '_id' is of data type null which can not be compared
```

The thing is that with one class (let's name it A) the method works properly, but with  the others fail and I don't know which is the cause because all the classes have its ID field declared the same way.
I'm getting this exception too if I try to `createOrUpdate` the object of any class, except the refered class A.

Any helping hand would be appreciated.

NOTE. The project uses an `ormlite_config.txt` file, which is updated.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours debugging I came into that the mentioned exception comes only when the class to be saved has one o more collections. As far as I know, the exception is thrown inside the `idExists` method of the Dao class. Having in mind that the `createOrSave` method surely must call it, that's why I get the `SQLException` in both cases.

And now, the workaround to solve this. Rather than invoking the `idExists` method, I had to create my own like this:

```
return DBHelper.getHelper().getMyDAO().queryForId(idField) != null;
```

And instead of calling the `createOrUpdate` method, first I check if the record exists and then, depending on the result, I call the `create` or `update` method of the Dao class I want to persist.